# How can I have Python return a value to MATLAB without is being casted as a NoneType?

Tags: python, matlab, type-conversion

I made a simple function in Python that adds two numbers and returns the result.

However, every time I ran the function from MATLAB, the value that MATLAB received was casted as a `NoneType` variable; the value had no answer whatsoever nor did it indicate what the answer from the script was.

I tried casting the result in the function beforehand to an integer, and then return the value. Nevertheless, the value that was returned to MATLAB was still a `NoneType` with no value.

I also tried to cast the returned value in MATLAB to an integer, but that also failed; it resulted in an error.

This is the simple Python function I made to test calling Python scripts from MATLAB:

```py
def add(n1,n2):
    n3=n1 + n2
    n3=int(n3)
    return n3
```

I call this script from MATLAB like this:

```
a = py.module1.add(3,8)
```

The expected result should be variable `a` in MATLAB of type int and with a value of 11. Instead I get this:

```
a = 

  Python NoneType with no properties.

    None
```

Comment: Can you show your full MATLAB code? You probably need to reload the module https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-modified-python-module.html